# Temporarily showing stdout while a command is running

Tags: io-redirection

I'm scp'ing several large files to a few servers in succession.  I'd like to see the progress (so I don't want to use `scp --quiet`), but I don't need to see the stats when the copy is complete.

Is there a tool that can receive input on stdin, echo it to stdout, and then remove it when the input stream closes?  This reminds me of stuff ncurses can do, but I can't seem to find anything online that does this.

For instance, if such a utility were called `echo-then-discard`, I could call it as:

```
scp lots-*-of-files "$server:$dest" | echo-then-discard
```

It's possible such a tool, even if it existed, might not work with the kind of updating `scp` does -- since piping `scp` output seems to just discard the progress (likely because ncurses needs direct access to the terminal to do the fancy updating).

Comment: I would just run your big `scp` in a new terminal window so you can come back to check on it whenever you want and can also leave it whenever you want.

Comment: Have you considered using `rsync` instead, with it's `--progress` and `--stats` options?

Comment: @they rsync is pretty sweet and has definitely made the overall process faster, so thanks for the tip :-) (leaving the question open because I'm still interested to know if a generic tool exists.)

Comment: @SeanAllred, Are you using a text mode screen or a graphical desktop environment? And do you want to keep previous terminal dialogue, or would it be OK to simply clear the screen (or terminal window)?

Comment: @sudodus I'd like to keep previous dialogue (otherwise I would use something like `clear`). I'm usually using a terminal emulator from a graphical environment.

Comment: @SeanAllred, With a terminal emulator you can redirect the output to less, for example (if you want to preserve colours), `ls -l --color ~/*|less -r` and when you exit from less (with 'q'), the previous dialogue is there.

Comment: I routinely use `tmux`. I would create a new pane, run `scp` there and later destroy the pane (exit the shell therein). Frankly I'm so used to `tmux` I spawn ad-hoc panes/windows dedicated to long-running tasks without a second thought.

Answer (score 0):

### Graphical desktop environment

A simple method is to use `less` in a terminal emulator window, simply redirect the output from the program,

```
program-name | less
```

for exmaple if you want to preserve colours,

```
ls -l --color ~/* | less -r
```

and and when you exit from less (with 'q'), the previous dialogue is there.

### Text mode screen

Many newer text mode screens do not preserve the previous dialogue, but you can install and use `screen`.

```
screen
# run some programs here

screen
# run the program from which you want temporary output saved here
exit
```

and you are back in the 'first screen' and its dialogue.

`screen` is an advanced program, and I know only some rudimentary features of it, but I tested that it works like this.